# r markdown longtable + landscape kable caption width shrinking (no longer width of page)

Tags: latex, r-markdown, landscape, kable, longtable

I am trying to use longtable and lanscape together for a wide table that spans multiple pages.  When I do this, the table caption goes from the full width of the page to just squished in the middle of the page.

I have tried using the following suggestions to no avail.
[R Markdown table caption width with kable and longtable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46085067/r-markdown-table-caption-width-with-kable-and-longtable)

I am new to r markdown, and I'm not at all familiar with latek so following the above instructions has been confusing for me, though I have tried all the options that I think are correct.  Can someone give me very explicit step-by-step instructions for where and what to put in the YAML to fix this issue?  Or does anyone have another work around?  Thank you for your help

```
test <- data.frame(col1=rep("MyLongWordsareLong",5),
               col2=rep("MyLongWordsareLong",5),
               col3=rep("MyLongWordsareLong",5),
               col4=rep("MyLongWordsareLong",5),
               col5=rep("MyLongWordsareLong",5),
               col6=rep("MyLongWordsareLong",5))

kable(test,format='latex',booktabs=TRUE,
caption="This is my example caption. See how, when I don't use 
longtable, it extends the full width of the table, but when I use the 
longtable option, it compresses down to only a portion of the table's width. 
Is this weird or is it just me?") %>% 
 landscape()

kable(test,longtable=TRUE,format='latex',booktabs=TRUE,caption="This is my 
example caption. See how, when I don't use longtable, it extends the full 
width of the table, but when I use the longtable option, it compresses down 
to only a portion of the table's width. Is this weird or is it just me?") 
%>% 
landscape()
```

**edit: I'm knitting to PDF!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "anonymous"
date: "14/12/2020"
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{caption}
output:
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: yes
  html_document: default
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(tidyverse)
library(kableExtra)
```

```{r}
test <- data.frame(col1=rep("MyLongWordsareLong", 5),
               col2=rep("MyLongWordsareLong",5),
               col3=rep("MyLongWordsareLong",5),
               col4=rep("MyLongWordsareLong",5),
               col5=rep("MyLongWordsareLong",5),
               col6=rep("MyLongWordsareLong",5))

kable(test, booktabs=TRUE, caption="This is my example caption. See how, when I don't use  longtable, it extends the full width of the table, but when I use the longtable option, it compresses down to only a portion of the table's width.  Is this weird or is it just me?") %>% 
 landscape()

kable(test, longtable=TRUE, booktabs=TRUE, caption="This is my example caption. See how, when I don't use longtable, it extends the full  width of the table, but when I use the longtable option, it compresses down to only a portion of the table's width. Is this weird or is it just me?") %>% 
landscape()
```
````

Solution as per [R Markdown table caption width with kable and longtable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46085067/r-markdown-table-caption-width-with-kable-and-longtable?rq=1)

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how what you have changed from what I have?  Note that I'm knitting to PDF.

Comment: When I add that to my YAML, I get the following error: Error in yaml::yaml.load(..., eval.expr = TRUE) : 
  Parser error: while parsing a block mapping at line 1, column 1 did not find expected key at line 7, column 3
Calls: <Anonymous> ... parse_yaml_front_matter -> yaml_load -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted

Comment: I think that's an indenting issue in the YAML. I've tried to fix that in the answer now.

Comment: Here's my full YAML producing the error. Hopefully this is helpful:

---
title: 'Report'
author: Michelle L. Stantial
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B %Y')`"
output:
  header-includes:
    - \usepackage{caption}
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: yes
    toc: yes
    fig_caption: yes
    includes:  
      in_header: my_header.tex
  word_document:
    toc: yes
  html_document: 
    toc: yes
    toc_float:
      collapsed: no
fig_width: 6
fig_height: 4
---

Comment: Sorry. Sloppy testing. I've edited again, copy-pasted and knitted successfully so should now be correct.

Comment: Thanks!  I think this *will be* the solution, but now I'm getting some other errors that seem to be related to connecting to the CTAN to download the caption package.  But this is progress!!! Much appreciated!

Comment: Yeah, just install `caption` using your TeX package manager.